# Django CMS dynamic image

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I need to dynamically change image background-image css from home page in django cms, but is imposible.

[home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVUVr.png)

CSS CODE

The css has the welcome-image-area class the user needs to change the image url in the cms.

```
.welcome-area {
    height: 100%;
}

.welcome-image-area {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/bg/bg.jpg); 
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}

.welcome-image-area:after {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML CODE

base.html

```
  <div id="welcome-image-area" class="welcome-image-area" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" >
              <div class="display-table">
                  <div class="display-table-cell">
                      <div class="container">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                  <div class="header-text">
                                      <h2>{% static_placeholder 'mensaje bienvenida' %}</h2>
                                      <p>{% static_placeholder 'sub mensaje bienvenida' %}</p>
                                      <a class="smoth-scroll hire-us-slide-btn" href="#service">Servicios <i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o btn-hire-us" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                      <a class="slide-btn smoth-scroll" href="#contact">Contactanos <i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o btn-contact-us" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In those cases I would recommend to utilize the "style" attribute as following:

```html
<div class="welcome-image-area" style="background-image: url({{ instance.image.url }})"></div>
```